# A BitTorrent client completely written in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, bittorrent

Is there a BitTorrent client written completely (I mean completely) written in C# ?
I am aware of the BitTorrent clients written in mono, I absolutely love it.

Are there any other opensource BitTorrent clients other than MonoTorrent & BitSharp written in C# which is under development?

Just wondering how much of an interest an "opensource bit torrent client in C#" would generate amongst C# programmer folks out there.

EDIT: Do check out Michael Stum's Pumpkin torrent on http://pumpkintorrent.codeplex.com/

@Michael: thanks for sharing the project url.

@Allan: thanks for MonoTorrent ;)

Comment: I've started writing a BitTorrent _Tracker_ in C# a month ago, with a client to follow. I am not aware of any good C# implementations of either, but i'll add a link in a month or two once it's finished.

Comment: Is it hosted as an opensource project ? Pls do post the link if it is one. For people like me who are willing to contribute.

Comment: If you're "not impressed" with the other options, why don't you start building a client yourself and get other developers to contribute? You're part of the C# open-source community as well, and you're welcome to help create the software instead of just insisting that everybody else work on that.

Comment: It's currently on http://pumpkintorrent.codeplex.com/ and as said, I am still working on the Tracker side and understanding the protocol. BEncoding is done, but BDecode is still missing.

Comment: Firstly I absolutely love monotorrent & bit sharp. I edited the question to change my tone.Honest apologies . It's only I feel it's got a long way to go to be on par with other open source BitTorrent Clients out there. & Yes i am part of the community looking forward to write one myself.

Comment: The http://pumpkintorrent.codeplex.com/ link is no longer valid, and I cannot find it using Google.  Does it still exist?

Comment: Just to add to this thread, MonoTorrent doesn't work for me and is really poorly documented.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

MonoTorrent is wonderful client and server library. There is a GUI written on GTK# - Monsoon for now it runs only at Linux. If you have a time to spend you could write a WPF GUI or with little modification to port Monsoon to Windows.

Look for Alan McGovern for more information.

Comment: Too bad MonoTorrent lacks any form of documentation.

Answer (score 34):

Unfortunately i don't have 50 reputation to add comments, so I have to write another answer. My question was directed at this comment:

"but honeslty I feel it's still got a long way to go to be on par with other opensource bit torrent clients."

What features do you feel are missing that makes it inferior to other libraries/clients? An incomplete list of features includes:

1. 100% platform independent
2. IPV6 support
3. Super-seeding
4. A full bittorrent tracker
5. DHT
6. Peer exchange (utorrent style)
7. Encryption
8. Memory cache
9. Prioritised downloading
10. Selective downloading (technically this is just a subset of Prioritised downloading)
11. Fast Peer extensions
12. Local peer discovery,
13. Ban lists (whitelisting/blacklisting of IPs at the same time)
14. Magnet link downloads
15. Endgame mode
16. Libtorrent extension protocol
17. rate limiting (per torrent/global)
18. Http seeding (webseeding) - getright style
19. Individual file relocation
20. What else do you want ;)

So, is it just a case of you not realising the full potential of monotorrent or are there features missing that you consider critical? If so, patches are always welcome.

""written on mono" is never a bad thing. It just I was looking for something on MS .Net"

I think you misunderstand. MonoTorrent/bitsharp *does* build and run on MS.NET ;) All you have to do is check the code out from SVN, open MonoTorrent.sln and hit F5.

Hope that helps.

Comment: @Allan +1 for the feature listing and extensive explanation. I really appreciate it. I think you have misunderstood my question, (but I think it's time I edit the question to change the tone) & Yes, I am aware of Mono Projects running on MS.NET. But thanks again Alan.!!

Comment: It looked like you were asking for a feature rich bittorrent library and monotorrent didn't suit your needs ;) So if that's not what you were asking, what *are* you asking? Anyway, the only other thing I can add is that monotorrent is the only opensource .NET bittorrent library out there :)

Comment: @Alan, is MonoTorrent still alive? Files section was updated in 2009. Thanks!

Comment: @ruslan, did you read the lastest News on monotorrent.com? **The source is now available at [github](https://github.com/mono/monotorrent/)**. YES its still alive.

Comment: On github no changes in 4+ years, and issues are piling up that make it look like it might not work in modern bit torrent world.

Answer (score 13):

[MonoTorrent](http://monotorrent.blogspot.com/)

or

[BitSharp](http://www.mono-project.com/Bitsharp)

Comment: Is there anything other than BitSharp & MonoTorrent ? Anything written on MS .NET framework & not Mono.

Comment: Wikipedia doesn't know of any: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_BitTorrent_clients

Comment: How is "written on Mono" a bad thing? It compiles to the same CIL. Provided that you have all the dependencies installed, you can run it unmodified on Windows. Or you could take the backend bits and build a WinForms/WPF GUI on top.

Comment: And by "run it on Windows" I mean specifically "run it on MS .NET".

Comment: "written on mono" is never a bad thing. It just I was looking for something on MS .Net I appreciate your response.

Comment: bitsharp is old name of monotorrent

Answer (score 3):

Also check out [Hadouken](https://github.com/hadouken/hadouken)  - fully written in C#, but runs as a Windows service. It could probably be made to run on Mono.

Comment: it is written in C++ not C#

Comment: It used to be written in C# but it looks like the creator is rewriting the code in C++. The homepage still says it's written in C#...

Answer (score 2):

What makes you think it's basic? ;) It sports more advanced features than a lot of other open (and closed) source torrent libraries. I think you've very much underestimated what monotorrent offers.

Comment: I absolutely dig monotorrent. I mean I absolutely love it, I do admit drawing comparisons is not fair.But by "advanced" what did you mean?. & again *I am not underestimating monotorrent.*. It's an awesome bit torrent client.

Comment: @Alan - And yes, Honest Apologies