# Peer to Peer file transfer c#

Tags: c#, transfer, peer

Hey, I have been looking on google and I cannot seem to find anything about peer to peer transfer.

Basically, I want to be able to send a file from my computer to someone else's computer. Does anyone know of any guides that can help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: Local network or across the internet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really just want to "send a file from my computer to someone else's computer" using C# then you may not be looking for true p2p. You can just use raw TCP. For this you need the remote computer to *listen* for a connection, your computer to *open* a connection to the remote computer, and start sending data.

There's a very basic example on how to do something like that [here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-simple-threaded-tcp-server).

If you *are* actually looking for true P2P then you're best off using an existing P2P network (otherwise there will be nobody but you and your other computer on it). There are a few C# BitTorrent libraries around - for example [BitSharp](http://www.dzone.com/links/rss/bitsharp_c_library_for_bittorrent.html), [TorrentNet](http://code.google.com/p/torrentnet/). There is a whole [question about BitTorrent libraries written in pure C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623635/a-bittorrent-client-completely-written-in-c).

Answer (score 6):

Google "System.Net.PeerToPeer", a namespace available in the .NET 3.5 framework.  You'll have no trouble finding docs and sample code.

Comment: Do you have any links to sample code?  The only actual code I find is a 2007 sample of resolving peer names, and the MSDN documentation seems to be a bit too much about the details of the classes and not how it all comes together.  Thanks!

Comment: Resolving names is what it is all about, the rest is easy.  The official technology sample is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb906998.aspx

Answer (score 3):

If the destination computer is able to expose a URI to publish to then you can simply use

```
WebClient.UploadFile(Uri address, string filename)
```

It very simply just takes a URI as address (http, ftp, even the file protocol to transfer to a folder share).

But that does require setting up something server side to publish to, but it would be platform independent on the server (e.g. any old FTP server, or a web page or service that accepts a file by POST method). Security may be an issue you need to consider however.

That's using a push model. WebClient can also be used from the other side to download. It also supports transfer of data streams, strings, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this project on [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/peer_to_peer_communicator.aspx).

It provides for P2P chat and file transfer and could be either an inspiration or a solution.

Comment: Thanks, but that is for c++, im looking for c#

Comment: The approach should be useful regardless of language.  However, I'm going to upvode nobugz.  I wasn't aware of the PeerToPeer addition to .Net 3.5.