# Best way for WinForms client to communicate with remote SQL Server and share data files

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf, ado.net, vpn

After much Google searching and at the risk of asking dumb questions, I could use some help.  I’m developing a C# WinForms client application using ADO.NET to read/write data from a SQL Server 2012 database located on the Internet.  That same application also needs to upload/download data files.  The client application will only be used by a few employees (ever).  The employees are all in different locations.  The database is only about 20 MB.  There will be about 100 data files totaling about 300 MB accessed individually on a periodic basis.  SQL Server 2012 is running on a (non-virtual) Windows Server 2008 R2 machine which we have full control over.  The client application will be running on Win-XP and Win-7 machines.

Priorities are 1. Internet security – keeping hackers out of the Windows Server machine and off the client/server communications.  2. Performance.  3. Simplicity.  Corporate security and scalability are not issues.  Also, performance is not that important if the solution is overlay complicated.

Two related questions I could really use help on:

1. Given the above priorities, what is the best way to communicate with the database?  The only two options I’ve found are exclusively; a WCF service or directly through a VPN.
2. And again given the above priorities, what is the best way to upload/download data files?  I’m sure there are many options for this using VPN, WCF, FTP; but I don’t know any specifics.  Also, using a SQL Server 2012 FileTable looks promising but I’m not sure how that works over the web.  Backup/restore plus being able to do a full-text search over the data would be nice features but not requirements.

I know what a VPN is but have never used one for these purposes.  I know there are some security issues with PPTP, but we won’t be upgrading the XP machines for a while.  I know what a WCF service is but have never written one.  I also don’t know if SOAP or REST is better in this instance.  I’ve built a FileTable in SQL Server, but I don’t know how to access the data remotely.  I have decent knowledge of C#, ADO.NET, and SQL Server.

I realize these are big questions with subjective answers.  Still, any ideas or a shove in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the best way I can think of would be to start off by doing a [Google](http://www.google.com)Search and search on how to connect to Sql Server in Winforms as well as web forms as well as WCF do individual searches and start code.. good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation would be to deploy a VPN server to provide the security you are looking for.  There are a number of good VPN servers available, and a Google search should provide a number of options at varying price points.

Once you have deployed the VPN server (and clients to all computers not on your local network that you would like to be able to access the database), you can use ADO.NET to access the database.  ADO.NET will work seamlessly behind the VPN.

From the context of your question I am assuming that the files are stored in a file system outside of the database, and the database merely references the files.  If this is the case, you could use any number of options for downloading the files, but FTP is a time-tested, easy-to-implement solution.  There are others that may or may not work better in your situation (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821680/peer-to-peer-file-transfer-c-sharp) for a few options).

Comment: Thank you both for your responses.  I decided to use a VPN because setting up for WCP would require too much rework at this stage of the project.

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple and use standard mechanisms. My recommendation is as follows:

- Build a WCF service that is capable of performing the operations you want. You can build a SOAP or RESTful service. My general guidance here is to build a RESTful service because you're transferring files and this is much more integrated with REST. With SOAP you have some setting you're going to need to fiddle with to transfer large files.
- Use SSL to secure the service, **keep it simple**. A VPN is an added layer of complexity and *very likely* not needed in this scenario. Further, it will only make the experience for the users less friendly.
- I would **not recommend** using the `FileTable` in SQL Server 2012 for your needs. You own the server so when you send and receive files it will be much more straight forward to deal with the file system.
- You can also build a simple forms authentication process that creates a session key for the user and passes it back. I'm not sure this is necessary, but if you need that extra layer, just make that one of the operations. Then that session key can then be passed into each method and validated before performing the operation. **This will be safe because you're using SSL.**

[Here is a tutorial](http://jamesheppinstall.wordpress.com/2012/08/12/restful-web-services-with-windows-communication-foundation/) that will help walk you through building a RESTful WCF service, and it's fairly new.

Comment: Thanks for the response Michael.  We are currently making use for strongly typed Ado.Net DataTables as well as BindingSource.  It’s my understanding that passing these objects through WCF could be problematic and inefficient as well as bad form.  Specifically, I have a hard time understanding how updates would be handled.  Do you have any experience using these objects with WCF, or converting this type of design into one that is WCF friendly?  Bad form is not really a problem for us if it works well.  Changing to something like WCF Data Services looks like a lot of work.

Comment: @rastro, when it comes to passing data back and forth you are going to want to build plain old classes. You can easily dump the data from a `DataTable` into a `List<T>` of some type of class. That's how you will send data back. As far as updating data goes, I would recommend sending each update as a single request (e.g. send the data you need in the form of very native types like `string`, `int` and such) and simply perform the update. I am also going to recommend you move from `DataTable`/`DataAdapter` to Dapper. Google it and you'll see why. It's simple, fast, and uses plain old classes.