# What all points should I consider while making asp.net application for torrent?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net, project-planning

What all points should I consider while making asp.net application for torrent ?

The application would allow user to browse, upload, download torrents. Further is there any particular standard for making torrents. Kindly share and enlighten.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Host on servers that are located in Sweden since its still legal down there.  Have a look at piratebay and copy them.

Comment: First thing to consider would be getting a good lawyer ;-)

Comment: Torrent in itself are legal... but the content that the particular torrent has is a different issue. I have to make a application for my client... now what he does with it is his headache... so kindly enlighten.
@broke ... i'll convey the server situation to my client... thanks :)

Comment: I'd say the main component is definitely the tracker.

Comment: You should be member of http://www2.piratpartiet.se/international/english :) 
Seriously torrents site is simply file storage. All you can to do is try to parse *.torrent files to extract and index info about files. If you want to develop torrent tracker http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623635/a-bittorrent-client-completely-written-in-c

Comment: Thanks @Sergey ... your response was really helpful.

Comment: Functionality wise, look at an existing app like vuze to see what functionality is available in standard torrent programmes

Comment: @Arseny, @broke and @Winston: You all make no sense.  Would you say similar if the question had been "What all points should I consider while making asp.net application for FTP?"  Or HTTP?  TCP Sockets? Lots of illegal content is available over those too.  Admitedly it smells a bit like the OP is asking for a server app, but even so...

Answer (score 2):

Given the number of torrent sites out there, you'll need to offer something they don't. IMHO, one of the biggest pains with the pirate bay is its dumb search. It seems to only search the title text, but it would be great to be able to search the supplementary text and comments.

Comments and ratings are also very important.

Answer (score 0):

A ".torrent" is just a small file uploaded via a form (or something similar). So, after that, you just attach some data in a database to it. There is nothing really difficult to it if you have some basic knowledge in database and web app with asp.

If you want to do a torrent tracker, that's another story and I suggest you to check for an existing one.